# How to revert SVN commit in PhpStorm

Tags: svn, phpstorm

I made a SVN commit with a wrong message and the SVN server obviously does not support comment editing. So I thought I could generate a "revert" commit and then re-commit with the appropriate message.

Since I don't have any command line SVN client (I use PhpStorm SVN plugin), I'm wondering if it's somehow possible to generate this revert commit in PhpStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my commit involves many files, I didn't use barmar's answer (which is perfectly acceptable for single-file commits), but I used patches instead:

1. create a reverse patch AND a non-reverse patch for the wrong commit (right click > Create patch)
2. apply the reverse patch
3. commit with a message like "Reverse previous commit (wrong message - stupid me)"
4. apply the non-reverse patch
5. commit with the appropriate message

Answer (score 6):

Another way to revert a commit that affects multiple files using the commit history:

1. With one of the affected files open in the editor, show the file's commit history with `VCS > Subversion > Show History` (or any shortcut method)
2. Right click the commit to be reverted and select `Show All Affected Files`
3. Select all the files in the popup (there are no checkboxes but the files can still be selected)
4. Click on the `Revert Selected Changes` icon on the topbar of the popup
5. A dialog box will come up allowing you to put the changes into a new or existing change list, which you can then commit as usual

Answer (score 2):

Use `Subversion->Show History` to get a list of all the commits of the file. Right-click on the 2nd-to-last commit and select "Get" to copy that version into the editor. Then Commit this to revert to that previous version.

Comment: Maybe because my commit involves several files ?

Comment: You need to do the first two steps separately for each file. At the end you can commit them all together.

Comment: Any alternative to rollback all affected files at once ?

Comment: This only works when trying to revert the _last commit_, not when reverting an older commit.

Answer (score 2):

This is tested in WebStorm 10, but probably also works in PhpStorm:

1. Open the *Version Control* tool window by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>.
2. In the tool window, select the *Repository* tab.
3. In the list of commits, right click the commit(s) you want to revert and click *Revert Changes*.
4. Commit with an appropriate message.

Comment: This is the easiest method to revert multiple commits of multiple files